# The name "BodyTag" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 and am completely new to ASP.NET programming. Nonetheless, despite searching Google and finding some things that looked like they might help, I eventually became stuck in this situation. Most people who get an error of the sort "name" does not exist in the current context do not seem to have very similar problems, and none of them seem relevant to me.

So far I have tried (a deleting and recreating the designer files, to no avail. This was recommended by some previous stackoverflow questions, and (b, this little workaround to be able to access the body tag from outside of the master page (that is essentially what I am trying to do here).

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelloWorldLabel.Text = "Hello" + TextInput.Text;
            if (Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"] != null)
            {
                ColorSelector.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"].Value;
                BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

        protected void GreetList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelloWorldLabel.Text = "Hello, " + GreetList.SelectedValue;
        }

        protected void ColorSelector_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("BackgroundColor");
            cookie.Value = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

BodyTag has been defined by this workaround here:

```
public HtmlGenericControl BodyTag
    {
        get
        {
            return MasterPageBodyTag;
        }
        set
        {
            MasterPageBodyTag = value;
        }
    }
```

Which appears to work with no difficulties, but ultimately did not fix the problem. I also imported the right classes etc.

Note that my master page has this:

```
<body id="MasterPageBodyTag" runat="server">
```

Just in case you thought that that might be the problem. Also note that this was created as a result of merging various pieces of code - I did not create this myself! I am only beginning out and working about with things as such.

In any case, all help big or small is very appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Okay found a slight work-around. Made a div tag on the default page and named it, then put it in my code. It changes the background of only ONE page though, not of the master site. So I'd still like a reason why exactly this code doesn't work, or else it'll haunt me for a while.

Comment: Read the title. Also, read "that is essentially what I am trying to do here".

Comment: Had it been clear, someone probably would have tried to answer your question by now. I recommend you better explain what your problem is, what you're trying to achieve and where exactly you get an error.

Comment: The part of the webpage in question is one in which a user selects a background color from a dropdownlist, and the background of EVERY page changes to that color. I get an error over BodyTag in both places, even though I have specifically defined it in the master codebehind. Is that enough or should I add more?

Answer (score 0):

Either you set

```
<body id="BodyTag"  runat="server">
```

or you change BodyTag in your code to `"MasterPageBodyTag"`